# How to get the country name instead of two digit name

Tags: symfony-2.3

How can I get the whole country name instead of the locale two digits using symfony2 form country type?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get it from symfony, you can try an external service like this:

http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?lang=en&country=uk&username=demo